# What happens when you return a self-signed certificate to the browser

Tags: ssl, browser, x509

In embedded software with web interfaces, it’s difficult to optain a trusted certificate for TLS.

So instead of greeting our users with a browser warning, I’m wondering whether we could ask the user to install the certificate in their browser before switching the connection to TLS.

Hence my question: What happens if you deliver a self-signed certificate to a browser via HTTP?

Typically, CAs would return your valid certificate directly to the browser, which installs it. So what happens when you do the same with an untrusted one?

Answer (score 1):

> Hence my question: What happens if you deliver a self-signed certificate to a browser via HTTP?

Depends on the browser and platform. It might just result in some download, might result in starting a certificate viewer ...

> Typically, CAs would return your valid certificate directly to the browser, which installs it.

That's not how it works. The browser will not blindly trust a certificate send by the server. It will check if the certificate is issued by a trusted CA, which is contained in the *local* trust store. The browser will not "install" anything.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your answer. Would you mind being more specific? So CAs do not send the certificate via HTTP to the browser for installation? I know that the trust check is done, that’s the reason for my question. Afaik for newly issued certificates the buyer can decide to install the certificate. In that case, it’s trusted. So what about a self-signed one?
Thanks

Comment: @Andy: As I said - no certificate get *installed* by the browser for certificates issued by a public CA. It gets validated against the trust chain, but not installed. See [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/) for details. With self-signed certificates the browser allows the user to trust this specific certificate for this specific site, which is different from installing a certificate as trusted.